# Why using namespace std is required every time you want to include iostream

Tags: c++

I know this is amateur but really want to know. Any help thanks

Comment: [Read up on namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Comment: It is neither required [fact] nor recommended [opinion]

Comment: related: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/509868)

Comment: How is this "unclear what you're asking"? It's pretty clear...

Comment: There is an immense amount of tutorials saying to write "using namespace std;" without properly explaining its purpose beyond "so we can use iostream", so I think this is a reasonable self-learning beginner's question.

Comment: @Barry I guess it's like when you ask a robot "Why does 2+2=5?", and then it says "I don't understand" and black smoke appears from its head...

Answer (score 4):

It isn't *required* just to include `<iostream>`, but using it makes the names in `<iostream>` usable without the namespace name, so you can say `cout` instead of `std::cout`.

It's not the only way to use those names though, you can refer to it by explicitly qualifying it with the namespace i.e. `std::cout`, or you can just re-declare that one name (and not everything else in namespace `std`) with `using std::cout;`

C++ namespaces are used to arrange and group related code into a common namespace. The standard library defines everything in namespace `std` so that the standard `string` type does not interfere with other types called `string` in other namespaces.